# Make only the ThreeJS model and elements underneath the canvas interactive

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to ThreeJS. I have a `canvas` that takes up the whole viewport to keep things simple. The canvas is placed at the top of the stacking context so that the model is always visible or never obscured by other elements on the page. However, because of this, the canvas captures all of the events on the page. I know that I can assign a `pointer-events: none` to the canvas, but I would like both the model and the rest of the webpage underneath the canvas to be interactive. Is there any way to ensure only the model is interactie, whereas the rest of the canvas acts as if it has `pointer-events: none` so that the user can interact with the webpage itself?